# Need help displaying array items in a slideshow fashion

Tags: javascript, arrays

Copy of my html/css and javascript. Stackoverflow wants me to add more information but I figure the title was pretty self explanatory (not to sound like a d**k). I want to display each Barbers name and their social media info in a slideshow fashion. I want the barbers name and information will change every 4 seconds. I don't just want the answer I want to know what I did wrong so I don't repeat this mistake in the future. Thank you. :)

```
function showinfo(){
    var barbername = ['Brian', 'Dwight', 'Greg','Josh','Tino'];
    var barberinfo = ['BarberPro','','Sunnti_TSN', '', 'ClipperDreams'];

    var bnameholder = document.getElementById('barbernamesm');
    var binfoholder = document.getElementById('barberinfosm');

    for (i = 0; i < barbername.length; i++){
        var currentname = barbername[i];
        var currentinfo = barberinfo[i];
    }

        bnameholder.innerText(currentname);
        binfoholder.innerText(currentinfo);

        setTimeout(showinfo, 4000);
    }

    showinfo();
```

Comment: Your setTimeout is occuring at the end of your showinfo function. The bnameholder and binfoholder WILL cycle through all of the array values, just way too quickly to actually see. You need to incorporate the cycling through values into the setTimeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several problems, but the main issue is - you need to increment `i` once for each `showInfo()` call.

In addition, instead of having two arrays, consider one array with objects that contain the name and the info for each barber - `[{ name: 'Brian', info: 'BarberPro' }, ...]`.

```js
var i = 0; // should be available to all runs of showinfo()
var barbername = ['Brian', 'Dwight', 'Greg', 'Josh', 'Tino']; // declare once
var barberinfo = ['BarberPro', '', 'Sunnti_TSN', '', 'ClipperDreams']; // declare once
var bnameholder = document.getElementById('barbernamesm'); // get and cache once
var binfoholder = document.getElementById('barberinfosm'); // get and cache once

function showinfo() {
  var currentname = barbername[i];
  var currentinfo = barberinfo[i]; 

  bnameholder.innerText = currentname; // innerText is a property and not a function
  binfoholder.innerText = currentinfo; // innerText is a property and not a function
  
  i = (i + 1)  % barbername.length; // increment i in cycle of 0-3

  setTimeout(showinfo, 1000);
}

showinfo();
```

```html
<div id="barbernamesm"></div>
<div id="barberinfosm"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! <3 If you don't mind me asking what does this bit of code do? " i = (i + 1)  % barbername.length; " I'm not understanding what the modulo operator is doing.

Comment: When we increment `i` we want to keep in the range of 0-3. The remainder operator `%` divides `i + 1` by the length of the array, and returns the remainder. So, if i + 1 = 4, the remainder will be 0 - back to the 1st element.

Comment: Oh! Okay. Thank you very much. I apologize if it's a remedial question. Never went to school for this. Only been doing this inconsistently about 2 years so I appreciate you breaking it down for me.